# I can't use celery tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have the following folder:

```
proj
 ├── __init__.py
 ├── celery.py
 ├── tasks.py
 ├── foo_launcher.py
```

Firstly, i have to launch celery worker.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

celery.py code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('project', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', include=['project.tasks'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.start()
```

Celery worker works perfectly but when i going to launch `foo_launcher.py`, i can't use the tasks because `foo_launcher.py` depends on `tasks.py` and `tasks.py` depends on `celery.py`. Here is the problem. I need to import celery.py file not celery library.

So, this is `tasks.py`

```
from  .celery import app #Here Import celery.py not celery library

@app.task
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
```

and here `foo_launcher.py`

```
from tasks import add

result = add.apply_async((2,2), queue='lopri',coutdown=10)
print(result)
```

All makes sense aparently but when i try to launch `foo_launcher.py`:

```
python foo_launcher.py
```

It launchs to me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\foo_launcher.py", line 1, in <module>
        from tasks import add
    File "C:\Users\beca4\Desktop\proj\tasks.py", line 1, in <module>     
        from  .celery import app                                                                                           
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I don't know what can i do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`celery.py` has the same name with `celery` module.

you'd better change `celery.py`'s file name, for example, `mq.py`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `__init__.py` file.

then lunch python.exe from one directory above and import tasks/foo_luncher.py -

```
cd ..

python
>> import projectdirectory.tasks
```

- projectdirectory is the directory that containing the `__init__.py` file.